# Variable reset after scanf

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc, scanf

I wrote the below function :

```
typedef enum {GREEN,BLACK, WHITE} color;

void StartGame(Piece board[8][8])
{
    color currentPlayer=WHITE;
    char location[2];
    int gameover=1;
    while(gameover)
    {
        printf("%d\n",currentPlayer);

        if(currentPlayer==WHITE)
            printf(BOLDWHITE"White: Please select a piece:\n");
        else
            printf(BOLDBLACK"Black: Please select a piece:\n");

        printf("%d\n",currentPlayer);

        scanf("%s",location);

        printf("%d\n",currentPlayer);
        if(currentPlayer==WHITE)
            currentPlayer=BLACK;
        else
            currentPlayer=WHITE;

    }
}
```

I print the `currentPlayer` on any level to see what's going on -> here what I get:

```
2
White: Please select a piece:
2
a1
0
2
White: Please select a piece:
2
```

Why the current player is 0 after `scanf`? I didn't touch it.

Comment: You read a 3-byte location (`"a1"`, which includes a null byte) into a 2-byte chunk of memory.  This is a stack overflow.

Comment: Also, always check return value of `scanf`, or you are bound to hit mysterious hard-to-replicate bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer `location` has only room for 2 characters and `scanf` puts an extra NUL character at end. Therefore you have a stack corruption issue. Just give more room to `location`, for example:

```
char location[8];
```

**EDIT**

Since you just want to read a string, I recommend you using [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), which allows you to limit the number of read characters from the input string. Thus, my code would look like this:

```
char location[8];
...
fgets(location, sizeof(location), stdin); //instead of scanf, fgets reads at most one less than buffer's size characters.
```

You only have to worry about the fact that `fgets` puts a final end line character (`\n`) at the end, but this should not be a deal if you just process the 2 first characters of the string.

Comment: Why the hell I wrote STDIN? :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you overwrite the memory occupied by currentPlayer when you enter a string in character array location. As it seen from the console output you enetered string `a1`. That to store it in array location it shall be defined at leat as

```
char location[3];
```

because scanf appends entered strings with the terminating zero.

It would be better if you would use function `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
sprintf(format, "%%%dX", sizeof(buffer));
fscanf(file, format, &buffer);
```